# Java won't run program in terminal java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, debian

I'm following the java tutorials on the [Princeton website](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/home/).

I'm running `debian sqeeze 64bit` and I have installed Sun java version 6.

I can compile and run the basic `hello world` program without any problem, using the terminal and the Eclipse IDE.

The problem is:

when I try to compile and run a program, which requires an argument input for example:

```
public class RandomSeq { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // command-line argument
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // generate and print N numbers between 0 and 1
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println(Math.random());
        }
    }
}
```

I can run this on Eclipse putting an integer argument, however it doesn't work on the terminal.

I get this error:

> emes@debian:~/Documents/workspace/IOput/src/randomSeq$ java RandomSeq 21
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: RandomSeq (wrong name: randomSeq/RandomSeq)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>   Could not find the main class: RandomSeq.  Program will exit.

I've tried to update the `/etc/profile` to include the `java-6-sun` on the PATH variable.

I'm not sure, what to try from here.

Comment: Is your main class in the default package? Are yo u including it in another package? If so, don't leave it in the default package.

Comment: Do you have a package definition in your sourcefile? If yes, go to the `src/` folder and execute the program there (with `randomseq.Randomseq` as the class)

Comment: If your class is not in a package, just use `java -cp . RandomSeq 21` (assuming that RandomSeq.class is in the current directory)

Comment: See [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) to understand how classpaths work.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you're trying to run your program from the `src` folder of an Eclipse project. `src` stands for “source”. The executable version of your program (the compiled classes) is not in `src`; it's in `bin`, which stands for “binary”, i.e. machine code.

When using the command line, you should first compile your program:

```
javac MyClass.java
```

and then run it:

```
java MyClass
```

But please, do not do it inside an Eclipse project's directory structure, or you will create additional files (class files) not expected by Eclipse at this location.

---

Additionally maybe you are inside a package. You can't run a class if you're within its package folder. You need to be at the top-level of the package hierarchy.

Example: suppose your class is inside a package named `mypackage`. Then in `someFolder/mypackage/MyClass.java` you will have something like:

```
package mypackage;

class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

After compiling your code, you must be in `somefolder` and issue the shell command:

```
java mypackage.MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your class has a package

```
package randomSeq;

public class RandomSeq {
```

If so, then when starting it it should be located in the folder *randomSeq* and the root of that folder should be in your class path and the package must be specified when invoking.

So, if your .class file is in bin/randomSeq then you could run it with *java -cp bin randomSeq.RandomSeq 21*

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother about the argument as that would give a run-time null pointer exception.
The problem is your classpath.

Make a list (ls or dir) in the directory you run java RandomSeq from.
Do you have a `.class file` there. If not run `javac RandomSeq.java` first to generate the class file